# Where to get Visual Studio CD images?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

My Visual Studio 2005 CD (Standard) is broken and I have to install it to me new PC. I tried downloading "pirated" ISOs, but they have illegal keys pre-pidded to the setup (cannot be changed). So where can I get the original images with which I can use my **own** cd-key?

Comment: You can get Visual Studio from Microsoft. VS 2010 is still in beta, and you can get it for free.

Comment: Where did you get your CD key?

Comment: I assume with the original CD?

Comment: Seth: I have purchased the VS 2005 so I'd like to use it.
SLaks: From the visual studio package.

Comment: SLaks: Why don't you read the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer: I can use the downloaded ISOs, copy the files to my HDD and change the product key from \Setup\Setup.SDB file.

[Here's where I got the answer from.](http://nayyeri.net/change-the-product-key-in-visual-studio-installer)

Answer (score 1):

You can get it in MSDN (if you have an account) or in MSDNAA (for students, if the university provides access). Visual Studio 2010 Beta is still free, but be sure to read its license! You can't release anything that you produced with the Beta version. (At least that's what the license of the alpha version said.)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling Microsoft and seeing if they have a replacement policy. Maybe if you send them back the broken disc, they'll send you a new one.